# opening new window in ie7 opens same target as base window but shows proper url in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a simple little form

```
<form id="loginform"> <input id="myinput" type="text" /> <input name="submit" value="go" type="submit" /></form>
```

in a very not secure way i want it to go to different urls depending on the input value.

here is my simple little jquery script that i am sure could be written more succinctly. (feel free to help)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();
var apple = 'http://www.apple.com';
var microsoft = 'http://www.microsoft.com';

    jQuery('#loginform').submit(function() {
    var pass = jQuery('#myinput').val();

if (pass=='apple') {
var currentloc=apple;
} else if (pass=='microsoft') {
var currentloc=microsoft;
}
else {
var currentloc ='http://www.mysite.com/sorry'; 
}
        window.open(currentloc, 'formpopup', 'width=800,height=600,resizeable=1,scrollbars=1');
    });
});
```

this works when i run it on ffcurrent macintosh, but not when i run it in ie7. then the popup window is the same as the window we are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you declared `currentloc` as a local variable three times.

In JavaScript it's all about scope, and every time you declared `currentloc` with the key word `var` you were basically saying that "*I want this variable to exist within this if (or else if) statement and not outside it*." Later on when you used `window.open` and you passed in `currentloc`, you were actually instantiating a new global variable since all other instances of `currentloc` had been lost.

Global variables are automatically created when you don't declare them with var (I think technically they are global properties of the global object, but I'm not 100% on that). In any case, it is considered a best practice to explicitly declare your variables and limit them to the minimum scope needed for your application.

Here is your modified code. I hope it works (tested IE8 quirks mode, and Firefox)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var apple = 'http://www.apple.com';
        var microsoft = 'http://www.microsoft.com';
        var currentloc; 

        jQuery('#loginform').submit(function() 
        {
            var pass = jQuery('#myinput').val();

            if (pass=='apple') 
            {
                currentloc=apple;
            } 
            else if (pass=='microsoft') 
            {
                currentloc=microsoft;
            }
            else 
            {
                currentloc ='http://www.mysite.com/sorry'; 
            }
            window.open(currentloc, 'formpopup', 'width=800,height=600,resizeable=1,scrollbars=1');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="loginform"> 
        <input id="myinput" type="text" /> 
        <input name="submit" value="go" type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation, i always get a little lost with the global local thing...